# Edge driver untrusted cert capability (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm doing automated tests in browsers, using Selenium Grid architecture and I use JSON configuration files to setup the nodes.

Is there any capability for Microsoft Edge driver similar to `acceptSslCerts` ? This option doesn't work I just tested it.
There's no documentation about it on [DesiredCapabilities documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) and I cannot find it in [Edge Webdriver documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/tools/webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

C# code, but can be easily adapted to Java:

```
var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
//Set Internet Explorer browser to accept the SSL Certificates by default
edgeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.IsJavaScriptEnabled, true);
edgeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually when I take a look at interface `CapabilityType`, and `ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS` constant, the matching String is `acceptSslCerts` so it's not helpful sorry.